# Display data from a nested (multilevel) array using blade template commands in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

we are building a huge system with clojure and mongodb. I am developing a admin panel for the system. But I'm using Laravel 5.4 (the latest version).

I managed to connect mongodb with php and laravel.

here is my question. 
our database has multilevel of arrays.

here is the database

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58def7eb06703609d370f76f"),
    "description" : "Tuxido",
    "publisher" : ObjectId("578bb0f0e403c10f2f490d8f"),
    "title" : "Tux",
    "label" : "Tux",
    "imgs" : [ 
        {
            "url" : "http://localhost:8088/ad/578bb0f0e403c10f2f490d8f-849ca60b06b9f79e337dd29f51f7ed384f205d1e46c68a19af6f3935c167d15a.png"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5908c91e0a975a7b6e97bc24"),
    "description" : "Since the first edition until 1992 ",
    "publisher" : ObjectId("578bb0f0e403c10f2f490d8f"),
    "title" : "National Geographic",
    "imgs" : []
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5907b0d00a975a7b6e97bc22"),
    "description" : "3 months old kitten",
    "publisher" : ObjectId("578bb0f0e403c10f2f490d8f"),
    "title" : "Bino",
    "imgs" : [ 
        {
            "url" : "http://localhost:8088/ad/578bb0f0e403c10f2f490d8f-31ec293361cf7d318a189b7678841935a404249718d5f6a4d10ee70017aa600a.png"
        }, 
        {
            "url" : "http://localhost:8088/ad/578bb0f0e403c10f2f490d8f-1884915f5d94c6566a9bc329b673b5b525ff09329500c596a3209356006de0e5.png"
        }, 
        {
            "url" : "http://localhost:8088/ad/578bb0f0e403c10f2f490d8f-a1f7b7bbb9cbb89dd7dd61e6aa26a6fde2357f01296ebe47956205858a4f55a3.png"
        }, 
        {
            "url" : "http://localhost:8088/ad/578bb0f0e403c10f2f490d8f-e86c731f23635e86ffb19333bdefba9761a6a2b8cbbc1ffe198acd6f7215e8db.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to get image URLs and display them in  tags.
so I've written this using blade template,

```
@foreach ($db as $item)
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">{{$item ->title}}</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">{{$item->description}}</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">
            @foreach ($item->imgs as $imgs)
                <img src="{{$imgs->url}}"/>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

but this gives me *two* errors.

[image: ErrorException 1]

[image: ErrorException 2]

how can I fix this?

Comment: Look at laravels logs. What is an error you are getting? This piece of code looks good to me.

Comment: hi piotr, I've uploaded images with error messages.

Comment: I think that your `$item` or `$db` isn't an object. Temporarily change blade `@foreach` with regular `<?php  foreach() ?>` syntax and use `try{} catch{}` block to find item which is not an object.

Comment: I get `$db` from my route file

`Route::get('/mongo', function () {
 $db = Mongotest::all(); 
   
    return view('mongo',compact('db'));
});`

and when I put that in to a `print_r($db);` it gives nice output.

Comment: As i said. Use `try catch` in `foreach $item->imgs as $img` loop. This will show you invalid `$img` object. And run `php artisan cache:clear` to be sure there is no problem with old error

Comment: I tried this mate.
   `try {
    foreach ($item->imgs as $imgs){
   echo "$imgs->url";
   }
  }

  //catch exception
  catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
  }`

it also gives `Message: Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys found the way to do this. If anyone of you got this kind of problem

> (Trying to get property of non-object)

you can use,

> {{$imgs['url']}} instead of {{$imgs->url}}

If database looks like this and you want to take values from status,

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123432132414657"),
    "status" : {
        "active" : true,
        "approved" : true,
        "submitted" : false,
        "deleted" : false
    }
}
```

you can use..

> {{$item->status['active']}}